# HTTP caching with pjax (jquery-pjax)

Tags: jquery, http-caching, pjax

Browsers and proxy caches use the URL as a cache key. 
In pjax the URL is used to request both the partial Pjax page and a full page, therefor both responses will be cached under the same key. This will clearly lead to errors as the partial might get loaded instead of the full page and vis versa.

How would one go about solving it?

The only thing I can think about is to to add a pjax tag to the url. Does pjax provide a built in way of  doing that?

Thanks!

p.s
I'm using Rails, just in case somebody has an extra elegant way of doing in in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

[jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) appends `_pjax=true` to the url in XMLHttpRequest.

The alternative approach is to only have one page for each URL.

This can be achieved with jquery-pjax by only sending full pages and using the `fragment` option.

A more flexible approach is to only send minimal pages and use AJAX to add all the shared site content - page banners, navigation, ads, etc. Most of the AJAX only applies to the initial page load and thereafter `pjax` takes over. This is the approach of [HTMLDecor](https://github.com/shogun70/HTMLDecor).

Comment: Sean, Let's see if I get HTMLDecor right. Aside from the 2 pages/url issue, The main difference from PJax is that HTMLDecor allows to modify the header content as well. Other than that they do they same things - the method of specifying the "Decor"/layout is slightly different.

Comment: Also, HTMLDecor defiantly looks like a good solution (I like the fact that you can have page specified css/js and that you have only 1 page/url), but I'm slightly concerned with the fact that I haven't seen it being used anywhere else. I'm on a tight schedule and don't want to have to deal with unpredictable things that come up later on. Do you know of any sites using it?

Comment: I use HTMLDecor for [my blog](http://meekostuff.net/blog/). I'm not aware of anyone else using it. You will certainly get more support using jquery-pjax (and it already does what you wanted). For the record, HTMLDecor is far more featureful than jquery-pjax, and it doesn't use jquery so the total JS is under 10KB.

Comment: pjax doesn't do exactly what I want - I don't want to have to include all my js/css on every page. I will take a further look at both. thank!

Comment: Any idea why when I click on an external link then click the "back" button, it loads the PJAX version of the page instead of the full page? In other words, in my code I check if the PJAX header is set, and if so, hide the header, footer, JS, and CSS. So it loads just an ugly white page with standard browser styling. My temporary solution is just to open external links in a new tab, but that's annoying. This only seems to happen with some pages, which makes me think those pages are cached as the PJAX version. Should I maybe check for the _pjax GET parameter instead of the PJAX header?

Comment: Well... checking for `_pjax` GET instead of the `X-PJAX` header seemed to work. I thought that was the main point of the `X-PJAX` header though... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.0 now comes with Turbolinks. Turbolinks is very similar to pjax except  that it loads the full page from the server, and then updates the body & title of the page instead of reloading it. No modification on the server side is required - the server always returns the full page. 
This makes HTTP caching trivial.